# "No database selected"... but only in a function

Tags: php, mysql, database

Okay, so I have the weirdest problem right now. My code is fine! It works PERFECTLY as I want and expect it to, which is a major shock to me, because every time I go to do MySQL I get endless problems that I can never find a solution to.

But today, everything works perfectly. So what's the problem? The problem is that when I try to wrap my code in a function, it just... stops working! I have error checking after every step and it works fine when in it's own file and lines. But I need to put it in a function so I can add parameters (hence the "extraQuery" variable), and "return" it so that I can access it from a separate file.

Here is my base code:

```
$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Unable to connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name, $link) or die("Couldn't connect to database: " . mysql_error());

$extraQuery = "";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM things " . $extraQuery . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", $link);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
mysql_close($link);
echo($row['content']);
```

As I said, it works completely fine as that is. But when I do this....

```
function getResult(){
    $link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Unable to connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $link) or die("Couldn't connect to database: " . mysql_error());

    $extraQuery = "";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM things " . $extraQuery . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", $link);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    mysql_close($link);
    echo($row['content']);
}
getResult();
```

..It stops working at the second line, telling me "No database selected". But as you can see, I am explicitly selecting a database that DOES exist and otherwise works when it's not in a function.
And just to stress this, it is NOT my user permissions, nor is it the name of the database; because it works perfectly when outside of the function.

Any possible aid would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Waterwaker, is the error on the web page shown `No database selected`???

Comment: @tereško Whoops, excuse my lack of knowledge of that. I rarely do MySQL so I haven't kept up with the new stuff happening. Duly noted.

Comment: @Ali Yes. That is exactly what shows up from the "or die" section written after the select_db.

Comment: @Waterwaker .. well .. PDO was added in PHP 5.1 (that's 2005th), and MySQLi has been around since 5.0 , kinda depends on your definition of "new stuff".

Comment: @tereško Okay, that was kind of rude. I said I rarely do MySQL. I learned the basics around 5 years ago and people were teaching it the way I wrote my code. So yeah, it's new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) your database variables are not available inside of the function. You need to pass it as an argument for `getResult()` to have access to it:

```
function getResult($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $extraQuery){
    $link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Unable to connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $link) or die("Couldn't connect to database: " . mysql_error());

    $extraQuery = "";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM things " . $extraQuery . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1", $link);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    mysql_close($link);
    echo($row['content']);
}
getResult();
```

Comment: Oh lord, yup, it was the variable scope. Everyone, please excuse my pathetic-ness. I don't frequently do PHP&MySql... around the other programmatic areas I come from, I've never run into issues like that so it was beyond my expectation. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

variables $db_host,..., $db_name are there because you wanted to hide your access, or the function is exactly as it is written here?

If it is exactly you may need to declare these variables global (first row of the function: `global $db_host,..., $db_name;`), else their value inside a function is uninitialized.

NOTE: It is not good to use this. Just think your code to avoid this and as advised use at least MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variables to access the database are not in the scope of the function.

You'd need to do something like:

```
function getResult( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name)
```

Then call the function with:

```
getResult( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Or declare all of those variables as `global` variables, like so:

```
global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;
```

This makes sure they are in the scope of the function. Otherwise, they are all undefined.

Comment: @tereško - Don't tell me what to do, especially if you have nothing else to say - There's nothing wrong with exploring the capabilities of the language and using global variables to determine if it's the cause of the OP's errors

Comment: Oh lord, yup, it was the variable scope. Everyone, please excuse my pathetic-ness. I don't frequently do PHP&MySql... around the other programmatic areas I come from, I've never run into issues like that so it was beyond my expectation.

Comment: Amazing how John Conde and I have the same answer, yet I've had the pleasure of at least one anonymous downvoter. Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare $db_host, $db_name,etc as global, or pass them to the function, like this.

```
function getResult($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass){
//
}

getResult('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
```